# Spring MVC Ajax upload PDF file for preview

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, spring, file-upload

I'm trying to get a PDF File preview with Js plugin PDFObject.
In order to do this I'm sending the PdfFile to my Server which save it in a specific folder. This step works perfectly fine I'm getting the pdf in the right folder.

But when I send my Pdf as an byte array in the ajax response and try to open it in a new tab (or in the PDFObject tag) I'm getting a loading failure of the file.

Client:

```
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "documents/preview",
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    data: formData,
    success : function(file) {
        window.open("data:application/pdf," + file); 
        PDFObject.embed("data:application/pdf," + file, "#pdf-preview");
    },
    error : function(err) {
        alert("Error : " + err);
    }
  })
```

Server:

```
final File file = new File("path/to/pdf/file.pdf");
response.setContentType("application/pdf");
response.setContentLength(Long.valueOf(file.length()).intValue());
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" +  file.getOriginalFilename());

fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(fichier);
final byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(fileInputStream);
response.getOutputStream().write(data);
```

Unless I escape the data like this :

```
window.open("data:application/pdf," + escape(file)); 
PDFObject.embed("data:application/pdf," + escape(file), "#pdf-preview");
```

Then the pdf load in the correct format and with the correct ammount of pages, the only thing being that their is no data in it, all pages are blank.

When I inspect the "file" variable in chrome console I'm getting weird stuff in each stream part of the pdf file like this :

```
>file
"%PDF-1.3
%�����������
4 0 obj
<< /Length 5 0 R /Filter /FlateDecode >>
stream
x�\�r9r��S��nFk����|�=Z�7�ݙ>x�@�-
7(���~_L�a����>�2�(���ٜqHQh
```